# What image format loads most quickly HTML?

Tags: html, image

I'm creating a video site with thumbnails. The users can upload a video and choose a thumbnail and have it converted, or have one generated automatically. I'm wondering, however, what format loads fastest? I want every thumbnail to be the same format. I'm not too worried about the quality of thumbnails as they're small, and just want them to load fast.

Comment: data URIs embedded in your HTML will undoubtedly load the fastest. However, they will seriously bloat the size of your HTML file. Instead of optimizing the file *type* you should be focusing on the appropriate image resolution, and HTTP gzip compression when sending data, as well as maximizing your bandwidth by using a production-worthy server if you're worried about load time. You're focusing on the wrong stuff.

Comment: you can use any image. but compress that image using https://tinypng.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use .PNG file they take so much time to load. Try to use .JPEG image with optimization. You can optimize with many online websites to use them on your site.

e.g http://optimizilla.com/

Answer (score -1):

JPG will compress images more than the other formats. This results in smaller file sizes, which means faster loading times.

Answer (score -1):

use .PNG and put into cdn #CMIIW